# Python pandas nonzero cumsum

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply `cumsum` on dataframe in `pandas` in `python`, but withouth zeros. Simply I want to leave zeros and do `cumsum` on dataframe. Suppose I have dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df =  pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,0,1], 
                    'b' : [2,5,0,0], 
                    'c' : [0,1,2,5]})

   a  b  c
0  1  2  0
1  2  5  1
2  0  0  2
3  1  0  5
```

and result sould be

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  0
1  3  7  1
2  0  0  3
3  4  0  8
```

Any ideas how to do that avoiding loops? In `R` there is `ave` function, but Im very new to `python` and I dont know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can mask the df so that you only overwrite the non-zero cells:

```
In [173]:
df[df!=0] = df.cumsum()
df

Out[173]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  0
1  3  7  1
2  0  0  3
3  4  0  8
```

Comment: Too simple to see it Thx a lot, next time Ill try harder to figure it out.